# Select Values Based on ItemID OR String Value

Tags: sql-server, split

I am wanting to build a query that looks at an existing Models table.

Table Structure:

> ModelID | ManufacturerID | CategoryID | ModelName

What I want to do is pass two things to the query, `ModelID` and `ModelName`, so that it returns the specific model and also similar models.

ModelName could be made up of several words *e.g iPhone 5s 16GB*, so what I would like my query to do is:

```
SELECT
     M.*
FROM
     Models AS M
WHERE
     (M.ModelID = 1840 OR M.ModelName LIKE '%iPhone%' 
     OR M.ModelName LIKE '%5s%' OR M.ModelName LIKE '%16GB%')
```

Is there a way that I can pass the ModelName to the query as a string and then have the query split the string to generate the OR statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I managed to get this working, following the advice given by [Kevin Suchlicki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2149023/kevin-suchlicki) re. fn_Split.

I have made this function even more complex than i intended to, but in order to help others out in a similar situation, here is my final solution:

```
DECLARE @CategoryID int = 1
DECLARE @ManufacturerID int = 3
DECLARE @ModelName varchar(100) = 'iPhone 5s 16GB'
DECLARE @ModelID int = 1840
DECLARE @Carrier varchar(10) = NULL
DECLARE @Colour varchar(10) = NULL

SELECT 
    I.*
FROM
    (
    SELECT 
        DISTINCT M.*
    FROM
        Models AS M
    JOIN
        dbo.fn_Split(@ModelName,' ') AS N
        ON M.ModelID = @ModelID OR lower(M.ModelName) LIKE '%'+ Lower(N.value) + '%'
    WHERE
        M.CategoryID = @CategoryID AND M.ManufacturerID = @ManufacturerID
    ) AS A
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    Items AS I ON A.ModelID = I.ModelID
WHERE
    I.Barred <> 1
    AND I.Locked <> 1
    AND I.Ber <> 1
    AND I.Condition = 'Working' 
    AND (LOWER(I.Colour) = LOWER(ISNULL(@Colour, I.Colour)) OR I.Colour IS NULL)
    AND (LOWER(I.Carrier) = LOWER(ISNULL(@Carrier, I.Carrier)) OR I.Carrier IS NULL)
```

I will now create this as a stored procedure to complete the job.

For reference, [HERE](http://sqlmag.com/site-files/sqlmag.com/files/archive/sqlmag.com/content/content/24006/listing_01.txt) is a link to the fn_Split function.

Answer (score 1):

Do a web search for T-SQL split function.  There are loads out there.  They take a string (comma-delimited or space delimited or whatever) and return a table of values.  Then just do a JOIN against that result set.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT M.*
FROM    Models AS M
        JOIN dbo.fn_split(@model_name, ' ') AS model_names 
            ON M.ModelID = @model_id OR m.ModelName LIKE '%' + model_names.value + '%';
```

Comment: fn_split does not appear to be recognised, can you advise?

Comment: Hi Richard, see original post:  "Do a web search for T-SQL split function."  It's a user-defined function that splits a string and returns a table.